# What does a docker read only mount mean in docker?

Tags: docker

The relevant documentation

https://docs.docker.com/storage/bind-mounts/

says

> For some development applications, the container needs to write into
>   the bind mount, so changes are propagated back to the Docker host. At
>   other times, the container only needs read access.
>
> This example modifies the one above but mounts the directory as a
>   read-only bind mount, by adding ro to the (empty by default) list of
>   options, after the mount point within the container. Where multiple
>   options are present, separate them by commas.

I expect that to mean that there is no way to write to the folder that is mounted in that way from within the container. But if I minimally modify the example to give me a shell session and mount the root filesystem

```
~ $ docker run  \
      -it \
      --name devtest2 \
      --mount type=bind,source=/,target=/app,readonly \
      ubuntu:latest
```

I see that I have **write** access as root from to the entirety of the host filesystem from within the container.

```
root@bde1f19c1de2:/# cd /app/home/
# Creates directory in the host /home folder
root@bde1f19c1de2:/app/home# mkdir patata
```

What does then mean that the mount is "`readonly`".

How do I make it actually read-only?

I observe this behavior with docker 17.05 as it comes with Ubuntu trusty:

```
$ docker --version
Docker version 17.05.0-ce, build 89658be
```

Comment: Could you post your docker version?

Comment: @garlicFrancium I have specified that it is the current trusty version.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how you can use `--mount` option as it is only available for standalone container from Docker 17.06 and yours is 17.05.
[Ref](https://docs.docker.com/storage/bind-mounts/)

> Originally, the -v or --volume flag was used for standalone containers
>   and the --mount flag was used for swarm services. However, starting
>   with Docker 17.06, you can also use --mount with standalone
>   containers. In general, --mount is more explicit and verbose. The
>   biggest difference is that the -v syntax combines all the options
>   together in one field, while the --mount syntax separates them. Here
>   is a comparison of the syntax for each flag.

That said i tried it out on docker 17.09 and still saw the same result as your decribed. Only to realise that the "`readonly`" option is working but your linux permissions are as such which is allowing anyone to write on it!

Since you are mounting `/` and writing to `home` directory which has 0755 permission by default [image: https://superuser.com/questions/303910/ubuntu-default-access-mode-permissions-for-users-home-dir-home-user]

0755 means public (anyone) read and execute. The execute is allowing you to execute the `mkdir` command[image]

If you mount paths or folder which doesn't have public access then you will see the `readonly` option works irrective of it being a root user or not inside the container, which is you wont be allowed to write!

example I am mounting home directory which has a `0770` which is public doesn't have any access!

```
[root@jakku-admin-1 ~]# pwd
/root
[root@jakku-admin-1 ~]# ll
total 8
drwxr-xr-x. 2 root root 4096 Feb  7 21:19 archive
drwxrwx---. 2 root root 4096 Feb  7 20:38 home
[root@jakku-admin-1 ~]# docker run -it --name devtest --mount type=bind,source=`pwd`/home,target=/app,readonly ubuntu:latest
root@3ce55bba8904:/# ll
total 16
drwxr-xr-x.  22 root root  253 Feb  7 21:20 ./
drwxr-xr-x.  22 root root  253 Feb  7 21:20 ../
-rwxr-xr-x.   1 root root    0 Feb  7 21:20 .dockerenv*
drwxrwx---.   2 root root 4096 Feb  7 20:38 app/
drwxr-xr-x.   2 root root 4096 Jan 12 21:10 bin/
drwxr-xr-x.   2 root root    6 Apr 24  2018 boot/
drwxr-xr-x.   5 root root  360 Feb  7 21:20 dev/
drwxr-xr-x.  29 root root 4096 Feb  7 21:20 etc/
drwxr-xr-x.   2 root root    6 Apr 24  2018 home/
drwxr-xr-x.   8 root root   96 May 23  2017 lib/
drwxr-xr-x.   2 root root   34 Jan 12 21:10 lib64/
drwxr-xr-x.   2 root root    6 Jan 12 21:09 media/
drwxr-xr-x.   2 root root    6 Jan 12 21:09 mnt/
drwxr-xr-x.   2 root root    6 Jan 12 21:09 opt/
dr-xr-xr-x. 592 root root    0 Feb  7 21:20 proc/
drwx------.   2 root root   37 Jan 12 21:10 root/
drwxr-xr-x.   5 root root   58 Jan 16 01:20 run/
drwxr-xr-x.   2 root root 4096 Jan 16 01:20 sbin/
drwxr-xr-x.   2 root root    6 Jan 12 21:09 srv/
dr-xr-xr-x.  13 root root    0 Jan 29 22:42 sys/
drwxrwxrwt.   2 root root    6 Jan 12 21:10 tmp/
drwxr-xr-x.  10 root root  105 Jan 12 21:09 usr/
drwxr-xr-x.  11 root root  139 Jan 12 21:10 var/
root@3ce55bba8904:/# cd app/
root@3ce55bba8904:/app# ll
total 4
drwxrwx---.  2 root root 4096 Feb  7 20:38 ./
drwxr-xr-x. 22 root root  253 Feb  7 21:20 ../
root@3ce55bba8904:/app# mkdir test
mkdir: cannot create directory 'test': Read-only file system
root@3ce55bba8904:/app# touch test
touch: cannot touch 'test': Read-only file system
```

Comment: I am sorry but I don't understand: I expect this to behave similar to `sudo mount /tmp/source /tmp/destination -o bind,ro` which causes write operations to `/tmp/destination` to fail with `Read-only file system` irrespective of permissions, including for the superuser.

Comment: I would suggest you try it with docker 17.06 and later version, you will get the expected behavior you are saying